# TXT file is only partially read

Tags: c++, oop

Would anyone mind taking a look at my code and telling me if they see errors? There is probably an issue in the for loop. From what I can tell, the loop only reads the first student (Spongebob Squarepants),and his major, but won't go beyond that student. Any ideas as to why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "gradebook.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void BuildTitle(){
cout <<endl;
cout << "Student      |--------------------------------Final    Final    Letter" <<endl; //47 to final exam
cout << "Name         |--------------------------------Exam     Average   Grade" <<endl; // 56 to average
cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------" <<endl; // 65 to letter - 72 total

}

int main()
{
    string input_file; //name of file to read data from
    string output_file; //name of file to write data to
    ifstream inFile; //file stream objects
    ofstream outFile;
    string str;


    char fn[20]; //char array for student first name
    char ln[20]; // same for last name
    char subject[20]; // and for subject
    int listsize; // integer for the number of students in the list to determine list size

    int b_lab, b_test, b_test2, b_test3, b_final, t_part, t_mid, t_final, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c_test, c_final;
    //declarations to store the different grades in each subject

    cout << "Welcome to the Gradebook Program\n";
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file which holds grades. Please only use .txt files\n";
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin >> input_file;
    cout << "\nOkay, now enter the name of the file you want to store grades in.\n";
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin >> output_file;
    cout << endl;

    inFile.open(input_file.c_str()); //Open the files for reading and writing
    outFile.open(output_file.c_str());


    //If the file is not open
    if(!inFile){
        cout << "\nInput file not found or unable to be opened\n";

        return 0;
        };

    //If the file is successfully opened
    inFile >> listsize;

    //below: create a dynamic list for the students
    Student ** list = new Student* [listsize];

    //below: truncate through the .txt file to gather information

   for(int x = 0; x < listsize ; x++){
        inFile.getline(ln,20,','); //third parameter changes delimiter to comma from null character
        inFile.ignore(1);
        inFile.getline(fn,20);
        inFile.getline(subject,17);
        inFile.getline(ln,20, ',');

        int sub1= strcmp(subject,"Biology");
        int sub2= strcmp(subject, "Theater");
        int sub3= strcmp(subject, "Computer Science");

        cout << ln <<"," <<fn << endl;
        cout << subject << endl;
        //above cout statements are only to check to see if the loop is working correctly

   }
```

(This is only a portion of the code. The .txt file it reads from is:

```
    6
Squarepants, Spongebob
Computer Science 90 72 85 96 100 88 80 91 92
Finklebottom, Joe
Biology 85 90 78 85 89
Dipwart, Marvin
Theater 85 72 95
van Houten, Milhouse
Computer Science 45 57 26 79 54 52 60 71 63
Simpson, Homer J.
Theater 82 76 74
Cyrus, Miley
Biology 74 65 58 62 71
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see

```
    inFile.getline(subject,17);
    inFile.getline(ln,20, ','); // <----- reads numbers after subject name
```

is intended to read numbers part from

```
Computer Science 90 72 85 96 100 88 80 91 92
```

But this line has no ',' separator. So you probably get **failbit** (from [getline manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)) and no more reads occur:

> The failbit flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if
>   the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have
>   already been written to s. Note that if the character that follows
>   those (n-1) characters in the input sequence is precisely the
>   delimiting character, it is also extracted and the failbit flag is not
>   set (the extracted sequence was exactly n characters long).